# Error 'class String' has no member named 'contains' when using .contains

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Basically im trying to make an if statement that checks if a string contains a certain letter. This is what I have so far:

```
void serialEvent() {
  serialData = Serial.readString();
  if (serialData.contains(String.valueof(X)){
    serX.write(parseDataX(serialData));
    serY.write(parseDataY(serialData));
  }
}
```

Im pretty lost on why this isnt working.

Comment: Ardunio's `String` does not have a `contains` member function.

Comment: Are you asking about [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? Yes, it does, indeed, not contain `contains` method..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius
Do you know what I would do then to see if the string contains a certain character? I swear I saw somewhere that .contains is how to do it. I guess not.

Comment: @JackW 1) "_I swear I saw somewhere that .contains is how to do it._" Were you looking at C++ code? Other languages might have string classes,  that have `contains` method? 2) Again, are you talking about `std::string`? If so, did you look through the documentation, that I linked to? More specifically [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius im dumb I was looking at java documentation not C++. My bad

Comment: According to the Serial.readString documentation the function returns an Arduino String https://www.arduino.cc/reference/tr/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/   I think indexOf() is the function you want.